# Remove rounded corners from JavaFX application

Tags: javafx

I've created a calculator in JavaFX but one thing frustrates me - it seems like the scene or the primary stage has slightly rounded corners, and these are visible behind the square corners of the buttons.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh8Wt.png)

I've played around with the background radius of the scene but can't work it out. Any ideas where this radius (if that's what it is) is set?

Here is my code and CSS:

```css
.root
{   
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
}

.label
{
    -fx-background-color: #999999;
    -fx-text-fill: #f9f9f9;
    -fx-font-weight: 500;
}

.label-main
{
    -fx-background-color: #999999;
    -fx-text-fill: #f9f9f9;
    -fx-font-size: 35pt;
    -fx-font-weight: 500;   

}

.button
{
    -fx-font-weight: lighter;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: gray;
    -fx-background-color: #E0E0E0;
    -fx-border-width: 0 1 1 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.del-clear
{
    -fx-font-weight: lighter;
    -fx-font-size: 9pt;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: gray;
    -fx-background-color: #E0E0E0;

    -fx-border-width: 0 1 1 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.button-bigger
{
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
}

.button:pressed
{
    -fx-background-color: #B2B2B2;
}

.button-special
{
    -fx-background-color: #EA9747;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
}

.zero-point
{
    -fx-border-width: 0 1 0 0;
}

.button-equals
{
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```js
package calculator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.*;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class UserInterface extends Application {

    private static int appWidth = 215; //230;
    private static int appHeight = 295; //300;
    private static int numRows = 7;
    private static int numCols = 8;
    private List<Button> numButList = new ArrayList();
    private List<Button> functButtons = new ArrayList();
    private List<Button> compButtons = new ArrayList();
    private Calculator calc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
//Screen s 
        Label screen2 = new Label("0");
        screen2.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        screen2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        screen2.getStyleClass().add("label-main");

        Label screen1 = new Label("");
        screen1.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        screen1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        GridPane screenBox = new GridPane();
        screenBox.getStyleClass().add("innerGrid");
        screenBox.setPrefSize(UserInterface.appWidth, (UserInterface.appHeight / UserInterface.numRows) * 2);

        //Set the row constraints
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            RowConstraints r = new RowConstraints();
            r.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            r.setFillHeight(true);
            r.setPercentHeight(25);
            screenBox.getRowConstraints().add(r);
        }
        //Set the column constraints
        ColumnConstraints c = new ColumnConstraints();
        c.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        c.setPercentWidth(100);
        screenBox.getColumnConstraints().add(c);

        //screenBox.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        screenBox.add(screen1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        screenBox.add(screen2, 0, 1, 1, 3);

//Create calc and pass the screen1 to it
        this.calc = new Calculator(screen1, screen2);

//Create 0-9 buttons 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Button tempButton = new Button(Integer.toString(i));
            if (i == 0) {
                tempButton.getStyleClass().add("zero-point");
            }
            final String tempVar = Integer.toString(i);
            tempButton.setOnAction(e -> this.calc.setUserInput(tempVar));
            tempButton.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            HBox.setHgrow(tempButton, Priority.ALWAYS);
            VBox.setVgrow(tempButton, Priority.ALWAYS);
            numButList.add(tempButton);
        }

//Point button 
        //point button 
        Button point = new Button(".");
        String tepointVarmpVar = ".";
        point.setOnAction(e -> this.calc.setUserInput(tepointVarmpVar));
        point.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(point, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(point, Priority.ALWAYS);
        point.getStyleClass().add("button-bigger");
        point.getStyleClass().add("zero-point");

//Equals, plus, minus, multiply, and divide buttons 
        Button equals = new Button("=");
        this.compButtons.add(equals);
        equals.setOnAction(e -> this.calc.calculate());

        Button plus = new Button("+");
        this.compButtons.add(plus);
        String plusVar = "+";
        plus.setOnAction(e -> this.calc.setUserInput(plusVar));

        Button minus = new Button("-");
        String minusVar = "-";
        minus.setOnAction(e -> this.calc.setUserInput(minusVar));
        this.compButtons.add(minus);
        minus.setStyle("fx-font-size: 16");

        Button multiply = new Button("x");
        String xVar = "*";
        multiply.setOnAction(e -> this.calc.setUserInput(xVar));
        this.compButtons.add(multiply);

        Button divide = new Button("/");
        this.compButtons.add(divide);
        String divideVar = "/";
        divide.setOnAction(e -> this.calc.setUserInput(divideVar));

        //Add button configs
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this.compButtons.get(i).setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            this.compButtons.get(i).getStyleClass().add("button-special");
            HBox.setHgrow(this.compButtons.get(i), Priority.ALWAYS);
            VBox.setVgrow(this.compButtons.get(i), Priority.ALWAYS);
        }
        equals.getStyleClass().add("button-equals");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            this.compButtons.get(i).getStyleClass().add("button-bigger");
        }

//Clear and delete buttons 
        Button clear = new Button("CLR");
        clear.setOnAction(e -> this.calc.clearUserInput());
        clear.getStyleClass().add("del-clear");
        this.functButtons.add(clear);

        Button del = new Button("DEL");
        del.setOnAction(e -> this.calc.backSpace());
        del.getStyleClass().add("del-clear");
        this.functButtons.add(del);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            this.functButtons.get(i).setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            HBox.setHgrow(this.functButtons.get(i), Priority.ALWAYS);
            VBox.setVgrow(this.functButtons.get(i), Priority.ALWAYS);
        }

//Create GridPane 
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

//Add nodes to grid pane 
        grid.add(numButList.get(0), 0, 6, 4, 1);
        grid.add(point, 4, 6, 2, 1);

        grid.add(numButList.get(1), 0, 5, 2, 1);
        grid.add(numButList.get(2), 2, 5, 2, 1);
        grid.add(numButList.get(3), 4, 5, 2, 1);

        grid.add(numButList.get(4), 0, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.add(numButList.get(5), 2, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.add(numButList.get(6), 4, 4, 2, 1);

        grid.add(numButList.get(7), 0, 3, 2, 1);
        grid.add(numButList.get(8), 2, 3, 2, 1);
        grid.add(numButList.get(9), 4, 3, 2, 1);

        grid.add(equals, 6, 6, 2, 1);
        grid.add(plus, 6, 5, 2, 1);
        grid.add(minus, 6, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.add(multiply, 6, 3, 2, 1);
        grid.add(divide, 6, 2, 2, 1);

        grid.add(clear, 0, 2, 3, 1);
        grid.add(del, 3, 2, 3, 1);

        grid.add(screenBox, 0, 0, 8, 2);

        // Set row and column constraints 
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < UserInterface.numRows; rowIndex++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            rc.setFillHeight(true);
            rc.setPercentHeight(UserInterface.appHeight / UserInterface.numRows);
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < UserInterface.numCols; colIndex++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            cc.setFillWidth(true);
            cc.setPercentWidth(UserInterface.appWidth / UserInterface.numCols);
            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }

// Create the scene and the stage 
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, appWidth, appHeight);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("Simple.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        //primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

```js
package calculator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StringCalculator {

    public StringCalculator() {

    }

    public static double calcString(final String str2) {

        
        return new Object() {
            int pos = -1, ch;

            void nextChar() {
                ch = (++pos < str2.length()) ? str2.charAt(pos) : -1;
            }

            boolean eat(int charToEat) {
                while (ch == ' ') {
                    nextChar();
                }
                if (ch == charToEat) {
                    nextChar();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            double parse() {
                nextChar();
                double x = parseExpression();
                if (pos < str2.length()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char) ch);
                }
                return x;
            }

            // Grammar:
            // expression = term | expression `+` term | expression `-` term
            // term = factor | term `*` factor | term `/` factor
            // factor = `+` factor | `-` factor | `(` expression `)`
            //        | number | functionName factor | factor `^` factor
            double parseExpression() {
                double x = parseTerm();
                for (;;) {
                    if (eat('+')) {
                        x += parseTerm(); // addition
                    } else if (eat('-')) {
                        x -= parseTerm(); // subtraction
                    } else {
                        return x;
                    }
                }
            }

            double parseTerm() {
                double x = parseFactor();
                for (;;) {
                    if (eat('*')) {
                        x *= parseFactor(); // multiplication
                    } else if (eat('/')) {
                        x /= parseFactor(); // division
                    } else {
                        return x;
                    }
                }
            }

            double parseFactor() {
                if (eat('+')) {
                    return parseFactor(); // unary plus
                }
                if (eat('-')) {
                    return -parseFactor(); // unary minus
                }
                double x;
                int startPos = this.pos;
                if (eat('(')) { // parentheses
                    x = parseExpression();
                    eat(')');
                } else if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') { // numbers
                    while ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') {
                        nextChar();
                    }
                    x = Double.parseDouble(str2.substring(startPos, this.pos));
                } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { // functions
                    while (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
                        nextChar();
                    }
                    String func = str2.substring(startPos, this.pos);
                    x = parseFactor();
                    if (func.equals("sqrt")) {
                        x = Math.sqrt(x);
                    } else if (func.equals("sin")) {
                        x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x));
                    } else if (func.equals("cos")) {
                        x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x));
                    } else if (func.equals("tan")) {
                        x = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(x));
                    } else {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown function: " + func);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char) ch);
                }

                if (eat('^')) {
                    x = Math.pow(x, parseFactor()); // exponentiation
                }
                return x;
            }
        }.parse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some test code for this?

Comment: No problem. I've added all the code.